# Can I use relative path in Spring bean definition?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way to use relative path, say relative to class path or /META-INF in **Spring bean definition file**? This is a bit different from using `ServletContext` to obtain such info.

For example: I am trying to define a filename for a embedded database H2.

```
<bean id="myDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:h2:~/mydb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE"
    p:username=""
    p:password="" />
```

`~/mydb` is not so desired as it depends on how and where you deploy the application, the home directory may not be there ... how can I make it to write to, for example, `/WEB-INF/dbstore/`?

BTW - I tried "classpath:" as suggested, it doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: @skaffma: updated with an example now.

Comment: I have the same requirements. Any ideas for this requirements?

Answer (score 6):

The following resource prefixes are always valid:

**Table 4.1. Resource strings**

```
Prefix       Example                            Explanation
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
classpath: | classpath:com/myapp/config.xml  |  Loaded from the classpath.
file:      | file:/data/config.xml           |  Loaded as a URL, from the
           |                                 |  filesystem. [1]
http:      | http://myserver/logo.png        |  Loaded as a URL.
(none)     | /data/config.xml                |  Depends on the underlying
           |                                 |  ApplicationContext.
```

> [1] But see also [Section 4.7.3,
>   “FileSystemResource caveats”](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-filesystemresource-caveats).

**Source:** [Spring Reference > The `ResourceLoader`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader)

But I don't really see how relative paths fit in there. Perhaps you should elaborate your requirements.

---

Thanks for the additional info. You're right, it can't work in this context

```
<bean id="myDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:h2:~/mydb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE"
    p:username=""
    p:password="" />
```

Spring never analyzes that JDBC URL, it just passes it to the bean. What I'd suggest is to use [the `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer):

```
<bean id="myDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:h2:${dbpath};AUTO_SERVER=TRUE"
    p:username=""
    p:password="" />

<!-- example config -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:com/foo/jdbc.properties"
                              systemPropertiesMode="override"  />
```

Now you can either configure the path in a properties file on the classpath or per system property. Actually, you probably want to do something like this (make the entire URL configurable, not just the DB schema name):

```
p:url="${dbpath}"
```

Comment: I have updated this post with an example bean I am trying to configure. For some reason, the classpath doesn't work for me ... Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Do you mean if I define jdbc url in a property file such as `jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:classpath:mydb`, Spring will parse it? Again, in my first try, the classpath doesn't seem getting proper replaced. thx

Comment: @Oliver no, you misunderstood that. It won't do that for you. You have to somehow set the property to the correct path